# JSON PARSE ERROR 200 Unexpected token

Tags: ajax, json

I got this error from my jquery ajax request.  ERROR 200 Unexpected token

Here is my JSON :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "answer": "sofo",
            "email": "jk@gmail.com",
            "secretquestion": "bestfriend"
        }
    ],
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Success!"
}
```

I validated on JSONLint and i got Unexpected token. I cant understand my fault. Do u have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: That JSON parses just fine on JSONLint for me (and looks completely valid besides).  No 'unexpected token' error here.

Comment: Works fine for me, too. I also tried it in the Javascript console and it was fine.

Comment: And if there were an error JSONLint would tell you precisely where it is.

Comment: Just to clarify--JSONLint finds no fault, but your code throws an error?

Comment: In your ajax code, did you specify `dataType: 'json'`?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is valid. There may be a difference in the token name (a spelling mistake?) when you are deserializing it.